# Can't move objects, only 3d cursor?

Tags: objects, transforms, 3d-cursor

When I use any command in object mode like, G or R, I cannot move the selected object, only this orange dot is moved. Not sure how I got here, but how can I get translation commands back to affecting the objects?[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to press <kbd>N</kbd> on your keyboard and go to *Tool*. There, make sure that under *Options* is *Transform*. You need to uncheck *Origins* and the two others. That should fix your issue.